# Python sklearn installation Error on windows

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I try to install sklearn library(on windows): pip install sklearn
I got this error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\abhij\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'

Any direction would be heartily appreciated.

Comment: How are you installing it? Are you in an environment? Does `python -m pip install scikit-learn --no-cache-dir` work?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

instead of

```
pip install sklearn
```

Also 3.9 version might have bugs right now, so downgrade the version to 3.8